# Helmet is for angular 2

Tags: angular

I have an angular2 with typescript based application which I will be deploying on nginx image in docker container. Is it possible use Helmet JS as security layer over Angular2 with Typescript in this case?

Comment: you want to use a third party js in Angular is that so ? angular is a js framework so you can

Comment: I know I can use third party  js. I want to know if I can use helmet js for security purpose in angular 2..couldn't find example of same.

Comment: can you elaborate what security purpose may be angular has features for the same

Comment: Web attacks like HTTP brute force and Dos or DDos  denial of service etc...

Comment: Yes i gues then you need to use a third party js lib like hanmer with angular guards . sorry my mistake posted it on answers tab , i was on mobile

Comment: Ehm Helmet.js is an express middleware, so it's a backend thing. what has angular to do with it?

Comment: @Rahul Singh can you give any reference link for the hammer.js for security..google search gives refernces with regards to touch events

Comment: @lexith I am new to angular so didnt know about helmet.js is an express middleware..Can you suggest anything for http headers??